# Play framework: 2.8.0 - getting Class Not Found Exception when trying to run SBT command

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to execute the SBT command on Play Framework project, but I am getting the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class xsbt.boot.Boot
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.boot.Boot
```

The current Java version that I am using is:

```
java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

The SBT version that I have configured in the `build.properties` file is `sbt.version=1.3.10`

I am not able to find any sufficient information regarding the above SBT error online, and I am not sure what I need to configure to remove that error.

Comment: Can you please share what is the command you are running?

Comment: I am tyring to run "sbt" and "sbt run".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused because java 11 and sbt 1.3 may not be totally compatible, consider using java 8.